# execute updates inside theano scan

Tags: theano

```
rng = RandomStreams()

res, updates = th.map(lambda x: rng.binomial(), 
                      T.arange(10))

final_res, final_updates = th.scan(lambda x: res, 
                                   sequences=T.arange(10))
```

Imagine that I want to implement some similar thing. The problem is that `map` uses RNG, so it has it's own nonblank updates to update RNG states. How can I force `updates` to be executed inside `scan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `scan` source code docs:

        ``` The function is expected to return two things. One is a list of
    outputs ordered in the same order as ``outputs_info``, with the
    difference that there should be only one output variable per
    output initial state (even if no tap value is used). Secondly
    `fn` should return an update dictionary (that tells how to
    update any shared variable after each iteration step). The
    dictionary can optionally be given as a list of tuples. There is
    no constraint on the order of these two list, ``fn`` can return
    either ``(outputs_list, update_dictionary)`` or
    ``(update_dictionary, outputs_list)`` or just one of the two (in
    case the other is empty). ```